# Whose house is next to Nabstablook's house?

Tags: undertale

I've looked it up, but to no avail. I read that you need the **Mystery Key**, but I still don't know whose house it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The house next to Napstablook's belongs to Mettaton.

You can buy the **Mystery Key** from Bratty and Catty for 600G.

Also:

> in the True Pacifist ending, you can wander around the game world after beating the last boss. Mettaton will be found hanging around outside his house in his Mettaton EX body.

Comment: Incidentally, inside the house is a series of 6 journals which gives you more of Mettaton's backstory, particularly on his relationship with Alphys and another character.

Comment: Who is this _other character_?

Comment: @TheVoidChaos I was trying to avoid saying, but... Napstablook.

Answer (score -2):

Nabstablook's neighbour is his cousin, the ghost, mettaton. Most people that have watched a playthrough of undertale or played it themselves would know mettaton as a robot who later turns into a different, more human like, robot. If you buy the key from bbratty and catty you see that there are 6 journals or diaries about how mettaton meets the scientist, Alphys. The journals/Diaries also explain how close nabstablook is to mettaton. that is where the 'cousin' theory comes from.

Comment: There is no "cousin theory". It is directly confirmed in-game that the house belongs to "Napstablook's cousin". So if you agree that the house belongs to Mettaton, it's a pretty straightforward connection that Mettaton is Napstablook's cousin.